# C: What's the right data type to use for file sizes in bytes?

Tags: c, types

If I use something like `double` to hold file sizes in bytes, this will naturally fail very soon, so which data type would I use? Nowadays a couple of TB are common, so I'd like the data type to be able to hold a number that big.

Comment: +1 for bothering to ask rather than just using something bogus. :-) And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will depends on you platform. On Unix System, you can probably use the `off_t` type. On Windows, you'll probably want to use `LARGE_INTEGER`. Those are the types used on those system by the function returning the file size (`stat` on Unix, `GetFileSize` on Windows).

If you want a portable type, `uint64_t` should be large enough.

Comment: After a quick Google session it looks like uint64_t is what I want. Thanks! I'm overwhelmed by the number of responses and the response time. SO is marvelous!

Comment: @EnibMoc1994: You could also use `long long` or its unsigned partner, which are guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

`long long` is a Pop Favorite :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called `ftello()` which returns a `off_t`.

With `fgetpos()`, you need a `fpos_t` variable - EDIT: which is not necessarily an arithmetic type.

So `off_t` could/should be appropriate to fit your needs, and keeps you independent of the actual data type sizes.

Comment: Just beware that `ftello` and `off_t` are Posix, not standard C.

Comment: If you don't have `off_t` you don't have `ftello` either and there's no (portable) way to get a file offset larger than `long`...

Answer (score 1):

size_t is the usual for filesizes in C, but the type of it is platform dependent (32-bit or 64-bit unsigned int on Windows).  I'd suggest __int64 (a 64-bit int) - should cope with up to 138,547,332 terrabytes.

EDIT: Just checking, the Windows API call `GetFileSizeEx` gets you a LARGE_INTEGER, which is a 64-bit signed integer.  So LARGE_INTEGER would be a good one too.

Comment: For the record, `size_t` is 64bit in size in 64bit builds.

Comment: It is _not_ an `unsigned int`, it is an unsigned integral type.

Comment: Apologies, @paxdiablo, it's actually platform dependent as you imply. On Windows using 32-bit it's equivalent to an unsigned int. Last time I trust what Visual Studio tells me. :)  Have edited my answer to be more precise. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t

Comment: `size_t` is not the right abstraction on many systems, it is meant to handle the size of objects. On a typical 32 bit system this would be a 32 bit value, whereas your files could be much larger than 4GiB.

Comment: Correct - "size_t" is meant to handle the size of objects, "off_t" the offset of files.  "off_t" translates to "long long" (64-bit unsigned integer) in most modern I/O libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at using `off_t`, since this is what standard functions such as [fseeko](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseeko) and [ftello](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseeko) use.

Answer (score 1):

The libc `stat` uses `off_t`, which is a typedef for an unsigned, 64-bit wide type. That would be suitable for a little while.

Comment: off_t is typedef for signed long long on OS X.