# Recommended data type for storing file size in bytes in C language?

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, filesize, int64

I made a function in C that finds folder size recursively and sometimes the number of bytes get very big.

Things work well on 64 bit systems. However, on 32 bit systems, things broke because I used `off_t` semantically (it is common to use it t9 represent file size). I need to decide for another datatype that can store way larger numbers.

What should I use? A simple Google search says `int64_t` but want a data type that describes file sizes.

Comment: I'm voting to mark this as duplicate of [C: What's the right data type to use for file sizes in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345059/c-whats-the-right-data-type-to-use-for-file-sizes-in-bytes)

Comment: Except, the voted answer uses `off_t` which is not what I want. It's too small

Comment: On some 32-bit systems you can make `off_t` to be 64-bit wide by defining `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` to `64`.

Comment: *"but want a data type that describes file sizes."* If you want a different name for the type, then use a `typedef`.